# How can I prepend a string to every value in an array in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a collection of documents like this...

```
{ name: "Bob", listIDs: ["1c2f", "32a1", "0ebf"] }
{ name: "Meg", listIDs: ["a844", "8132", "b246"] }
...
```

How might I prepend the string "0000" to every value in listIDs for every document? e.g.

```
{ name: "Bob", listIDs: ["00001c2f", "000032a1", "00000ebf"] }
{ name: "Meg", listIDs: ["0000a844", "00008132", "0000b246"] }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `listIDs` array
- `$concat` to concat `0000` with element value

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
  [{
    $set: {
      listIDs: {
        $map: {
          input: "$listIDs",
          in: { $concat: ["0000", "$$this"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4G5nAINSbzn)

Comment: Thanks Turivishal! This looks perfect. I've never seen $$this before - I guess aggregation pipelines can really do anything these days! :) I'll give it a go now.