# How can I update a property within an array of objects based on it's existing value in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have some documents with the following structure...

```
{
    user: "Joe",
    lists: [
        { listId: "1234", listName: "dogs" },
        { listId: "5678", listName: "cats" }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to prepend a string to each listId field but I am stuck. Amongst other things I have tried...

```
db.users.updateMany(
    {"lists.listId": /^[0-9a-f]{20,}$/},
    [{$set:
        {"lists.listId.$[]": {"$concat": ["0000", "$lists.listId"]}}
    }]
)
```

But I got the error message: "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'"

Variations on this write results into the appropriate field, but not the results I'm after.

I've bashed my head against the docs for a few hours now but all the references I can find to using the positional operator to reference the value of the field that is being updated use the field name directly, not referenced as a property like I am doing. I've not really messed with pipelines a lot before and I'm finding it all a bit confusing! Someone kindly helped me with a [closely related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67740432/how-can-i-prepend-a-string-to-every-value-in-an-array-in-mongoose) yesterday, using $map, and that worked great for a plain array of strings but I haven't had any luck adapting that to an array of objects with string properties. Sorry if this is Mongo 101, the docs are good, but there's a lot of them and I'm not sure which bits are relevant to this.

Comment: Are you trying to update all items in `lists` array for all documents in the collection?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. It's a one time operation / migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
db.collection.users({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      lists: {
        $map: {
          input: "$lists",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                "listName": "$$this.listName",
                "listId": {
                  $concat: [
                    "0000",
                    "$$this.listId"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q8kUTB6X5JY

Comment: Thanks a million dude! Gallingly I'd got within a few characters of this at one point this evening but I never thought to try $$this.listId. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Actually I just tried it and, while it prepends the zeros to the listIds correctly, it replaces the original objects with those updated listIds. I need something that will change the listId fields in place (and also leave the listNames as they are). My example wasn't clear, I will update it. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Let me check it again.

Comment: I updated my code. Can you check it again?

Comment: Yes that works perfectly Nenad, thank you so much for your time!